# Changing the URL of an HTTPS server

Tags: apache, https

Hello Stack Overflowers,
    I am a newbie to servers (and Linux in general). I have recently made an HTTP server on Kali Linux (formerly BACKTRACK). When I type in http://localhost/ it works and my HTML page shows up. BUT I want to change the URL to be https://localhost/ The server software that I am using is Apache.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Thomas

Comment: What URL you would want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://localhost means, that your Computer does not fetch the site from the internet. You can test this by trying to view your site while offline - this will work.

If you want another domain name, you have to put your site on the internet.
Find a hosting provider, make a contract, choose a name for your site that's not already taken, load up your page.

Be aware that this might cost something.

If you want to change the name only locally, open the file `/etc/hosts`
as superuser.
It should look like

```
# Comments Here
127.0.0.1     localhost
# End of /etc/hosts
```

Add

```
# Comments Here
127.0.0.1     localhost yourdomain.name
# End of /etc/hosts
```

Note that your site then can only be viewed on your computer.